# php variables in jquery script

Tags: php, jquery

I have these php variables:

```
$n= $json['health'];
$n2= $json2['health'];
```

The output are numbers.

Here is the jquery script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
var valMap = [0, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500];
$("#slider-range").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {                        
        $("#amount").val(valMap[ui.value]);                
    }       
});
//$("#amount").val(valMap[ui.value]);
})
</script>
```

I tried to get the vars in the script as my php variables like that:

```
var valMap = ['<?php echo($n); echo($n2);?>';];
```

How can I set the variables in the right way?

Comment: what do $n and $n2 look like? can you show a `var_dump($n)`?

Comment: Two Numbers. 152 and 204. This is the php output.

Comment: then it would be `var valMap = ['<?php echo $n .", " . $n2; ?>'];`

Comment: apart from the missing `,` you also had a `;` to much here: `;?>';];`

Comment: @Jeff Why adding the single quote inside the `var valMap =  [ ]`

Comment: @benjarobin you're right, I forgot to remove them!

Comment: @Kelster use benjarobin's answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like that:

```
var valMap = [<?php echo "$n, $n2"; ?>];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that:

```
var valMap = [<?php echo $n.",".$n2; ?>];
```

Comment: No, this is going to print: `var valMap = [3..67];`

Comment: sorry there was an issue in echo. I have changed it now. Please try again with my changes

Comment: Yes, now it's right, but this answer is very similar with my own answer, and this answer is already (almost) in a comment...

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array with these variables in your PHP code.

```
$n_arr=array($json['health'],$json2['health']);
```

Then in your script use that array like this.

```
var valMap = <?php echo json_encode($n_arr);  ?>;
```

This should be the tidy way to do it!